# Access google spreadheet using python

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, google-sheets

hey i have been trying to access Google spreadsheet using Python But was no success

If Possible can someone please suggest how can one access google spreadsheet using python in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [google data python libraries](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/python_client_lib)?

You can find the download page [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list) get the latest version unpack it CD into the folder and run `./setup.py install`

The [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/gdata/docs/api.html) is available online.

Here is [a blog post](http://mrwoof.tumblr.com/post/1004514567/using-google-python-api-to-get-rows-from-a-google) using the python api to get data from a spreadsheet.

In case the content of the post is removed at a later date I have copied the code contained below:

```
import socket
import logging
import atom.service
import gdata.service
import gdata.spreadsheet
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.spreadsheet.text_db

class SampleFetcher():
    def run(self, from_date=None, to_date=None):
        self.getGoogleEntries(from_date, to_date)

    def getGoogleEntries(self, from_date=None, to_date=None):                
        """
        Sample code to fetch data from a Google Spreadsheet using a query and a sort, followed
        by example of how to get the data out by column name.

        This code assumes you have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

        Timestamp       |   First Name  |   Last Name
        8/16/2010 12:15:00  |   Michael     |   Woof
        8/17/2010 14:25:35  |   John        |   Doe          

        Google Spreadsheets normalizes the column names for the purposes of the API by stripping all non-alphanumerics and lower-casing,
        hence the column names used in the code as "timestamp", "firstname", and "lastname".
        """
        gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
        gd_client.email = 'YOUR_EMAIL'
        gd_client.password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
        gd_client.source = 'YOUR_APP_NAME'

        try:                    
        # log in
            gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
        except socket.sslerror, e:
            logging.error('Spreadsheet socket.sslerror: ' + str(e))
            return False

    key = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_KEY'
    wksht_id = 'YOUR_WORKSHEET_ID'

        q = gdata.spreadsheet.service.ListQuery()
        q.orderby = 'column:firstname'
        q.reverse = 'true'

        # Here's the actual query
        if from_date and to_date:
            q.sq = 'timestamp >= %s and timestamp <= %s' % (from_date, to_date)
        elif from_date:
            q.sq = 'timestamp >= %s' % from_date
        elif to_date:
            q.sq = 'timestamp <= %s' % to_date

        try:
        # fetch the spreadsheet data
            feed = gd_client.GetListFeed(key, wksht_id, query=q)
        except gdata.service.RequestError, e:
            logging.error('Spreadsheet gdata.service.RequestError: ' + str(e))
            return False
        except socket.sslerror, e:
            logging.error('Spreadsheet socket.sslerror: ' + str(e))
            return False

        # Iterate over the rows
        for row_entry in feed.entry:
        # to get the column data out, you use the text_db.Record class, then use the dict record.content
            record = gdata.spreadsheet.text_db.Record(row_entry=row_entry)
            print "%s,%s,%s" % (record.content['timestamp'], record.content['firstname'], record.content['lastname'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SampleFetcher().run()
```